# Retrieving latest inbox messages and comments from Instagram Graph API

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I wanted to know how I can retrieve instagram messages and comments on my posts using the Instagram Graph API available to us by Meta. I already have everything set up, like a facebook developer account, an Instagram business account etc. I can play with the Graph API explorer but the documentation for what I need isn't very helping. I don't know which endpoints to use in order to get what I want (if it is even possible to retrieve them). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Farhan

I tried various endpoints in the Graph API explorer but none seemed to work for what I need